# How to parse anonymous object using JDT?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

From code here, I want to get `new Foo();` only :

```
class Foo{
    public Foo(){
    }
    public Foo(int a){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    public void fo(){
        System.out.println(test);
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Foo foo = new Foo(1);
        new Foo();
        new Foo().fo();
    }
}
```

I have try using JDT to parse my code, so my code like here :

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS2);
parser.setSource(myCode.getText().toCharArray());
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
    @Override
    public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node){
        System.out.println(node.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean visit(ConstructorInvocation node) {
        System.out.println(node.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean visit(AnonymousClassDeclaration node) {
        System.out.println(node.toString());
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I'm search my problem for a long time, I have get an answer from [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ClassInstanceCreation)

Add your code :

```
@Override
public boolean visit(ClassInstanceCreation node) {
    System.out.println("ClassInstanceCreation : "+node.toString());
    return false;
}
```